# Writing swap function to reassign member values in an array of structures in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, heapsort

I'm writing a program that will create a priority queue organized from highest to lowest priority (smallest number being highest priority) using heapsort.

I have a program that can read in an arbitrary number of nodes, first its value and its priority. I added a third member, location, which keeps track of where the node is in the array. Each time I add a node to the array, I increment the size of the heap(starting at 0). Since the node is being added to the end of the array, its initial location is equal to the size of the heap.

When I perform a sort, I compare the priority of each node to its child nodes. If the child node has a lower priority than its parent, the swap function I wrote should swap the priority of the two nodes, and the value of the two nodes. I've attached the build heap, heapify up, and swap functions below :

```
    void Heap::buildheap(heaptype *A, heaptype node)
    {
            for(int i = heapsize; i>0; i--)
            {
                    heapifyup(A,A[i-heapsize]);
            }
    }      

    void Heap::heapifyup(heaptype *A, heaptype node)
    {
            heaptype min;
            heaptype r = getright(A, node);
            heaptype l = getleft(A, node);

            if(l.location<=heapsize && l.k<node.k)
            {
                    min = l;
            }

            else
            {
                    min = node;
            }

            if(r.location<=heapsize && r.k<min.k)
            {
                    min = r;
            }

            if(min.k != node.k)
            {
                    Swap(min,node);
                    heapifyup(A, min);
            }

    }

    heaptype Heap::Swap (struct heaptype a,struct heaptype b)
    {
            heaptype temp;
            temp.id = a.id;
            a.id = b.id;
            b.id = temp.id;
            temp.k = a.k;
            a.k = b.k;
            b.k = temp.k;

        return(a, b);
    }
```

This is the same code showing the flags I put:

```
    void Heap::heapifyup(heaptype *A, heaptype node)
    {
    ...
            if(min.k != node.k)
            {
                    cout<<"1Minimum id: "<<min.id<<endl;
                    cout<<"1Minimum priority: "<<min.k<<endl;
                    cout<<"1Minimum location: "<<min.location<<endl;
                    cout<<"1node id: "<<node.id<<endl;
                    cout<<"1node priority: "<<node.k<<endl;
                    cout<<"1node location: "<<node.location<<endl;

                    Swap(min,node);

                    cout<<"final Minimum id: "<<min.id<<endl;
                    cout<<"final Minimum priority: "<<min.k<<endl;
                    cout<<"final Minimum location: "<<min.location<<endl;
                    cout<<"final node id: "<<node.id<<endl;
                    cout<<"final node priority: "<<node.k<<endl;
                    cout<<"final node location: "<<node.location<<endl;

                    heapifyup(A, min);

            }

    }
```

and

```
    heaptype Heap::Swap (struct heaptype a,struct heaptype b)
    {
            cout<<"intial a id: "<<a.id<<endl;
            cout<<"initial a priority: "<<a.k<<endl;
            cout<<"initial a location: "<<a.location<<endl;
            cout<<"initial b id: "<<b.id<<endl;
            cout<<"initial b priority: "<<b.k<<endl;
            cout<<"initial b location: "<<b.location<<endl;

            heaptype temp;
            temp.id = a.id;
            a.id = b.id;
            b.id = temp.id;
            temp.k = a.k;
            a.k = b.k;
            b.k = temp.k;

            cout<<"final a id: "<<a.id<<endl;
            cout<<"final a priority: "<<a.k<<endl;
            cout<<"final a location: "<<a.location<<endl;
            cout<<"final b id: "<<b.id<<endl;
            cout<<"final b priority: "<<b.k<<endl;
            cout<<"final b location: "<<b.location<<endl;

        return(a, b);
    }
```

which show that with input (2 3, 3 2), heapifyup function will identify which priority is smallest, and the swap function will exchange the value and priority for each node, but when I call the swap function it doesn't appear to have any affect on the nodes in the heapifyup function.

Comment: Please format the code properly, and make your question more concise. Those walls of text are hard to read, partly because of lack of structure and paragraphs, and partly because of the "this is my first time posting", "If anyone could" tangents that just dilute the meaning.

Comment: Keep in mind heapify does not sort the list it creates a complete tree with a heap property. Sorting and making a heap are two different things. You should not have to sort a list for a priority queue. creating a heap is much more performant than Sorting the entire list in a priority queue.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that in your `Swap` function, you are taking the arguments by-value, returning a new one and not assigning it to anything. The expression `return(a,b);` doesn't do what you think it does: the default comma operator in C++ evaluates its first argument, then returns the second argument, so `return(a,b);` is the same as `return b;`. You could return a `std::pair<heaptype,heaptype>` and assign the contents at the call site, but your best option is to just take the arguments by reference:

```
heaptype Swap (struct heaptype a,struct heaptype b);
void Swap (heaptype& a, heaptype& b); //change to this
```

Comment: Thank you and Joachim for your help! It still isn't working yet, but I'm going to work until I get stuck again. I have an idea it's just more of the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems: The first is that when you pass arguments to a function by value, the values are *copied* and changing the values inside the function will only modify the copies and not the originals. C++ allows you to pass *by reference* meaning that the arguments are references of the originals and changing an argument inside the function will also modify the original (because they are both the same).

The second problem you have is your return statement. You can't return multiple values from a function, in fact you're using the comma expression, which evaluates both sub-expression on both sides of the comma, but returs the value of the right side. So `return a,b` is in essence equal to `return b`.

Depending on what you want to do, you can either pass the arguments by reference, like

```
void Swap (struct heaptype& a, struct heaptype& b)
```

(Note the ampersand)

Or if you want to pass by value and return two values, you can return a [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair):

```
std::pair<heaptype, heaptype> Swap (struct heaptype a, struct heaptype b)
{
    ...

    return std::make_pair(a, b);
}
```

---

If you want to swap the whole structures, you could use [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) instead.